# Hiding (Obfuscating) Java script

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

So i heard that obfuscating java script is useless and waste of time because anyone with a little of skill can decode your code. So i want to test that. This code will display a alert box saying hey if you execute it. But there is more code than that in there. So here is the code obfuscated more than once who can decode it?

```
eval(function(e,r,n,c,t,i){if(t=function(e){return(r>e?"":t(e/r))+String.fromCharCode(e%r+161)},!"".replace(/^/,String)){for(;n--;)i[t(n)]=c[n]||t(n);c=[function(e){return i[e]}],t=function(){return"[¡-ÿ]+"},n=1}for(;n--;)c[n]&&(e=e.replace(RegExp(t(n),"g"),c[n]));return e}("õ(¬(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=¬(c){³ c};º(!''.Í(/^/,Ö)){¾(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[¬(e){³ d[e]}];e=¬(){³'\\\\w+'};c=1};¾(c--){º(k[c]){p=p.Í(ö ð('\\\\b'+e(c)+'\\\\b','g'),k[c])}}³ p}('¢«(µ(¥,¤,¡,£,¢,§){¢=µ(¡){¶(¡<¤?\\'\\':¢(Ý(¡/¤)))+((¡=¡%¤)>ò?Á.ÿ(¡+Ä):¡.â(ã))};È(!\\'\\'.¼(/^/,Á)){Ì(¡--){§[¢(¡)]=£[¡]||¢(¡)}£=[µ(¢){¶ §[¢]}];¢=µ(){¶\\'\\\\\\\\©+\\'};¡=1};Ì(¡--){È(£[¡]){¥=¥.¼(¢¤ ø(\\'\\\\\\\\¦\\'+¢(¡)+\\'\\\\\\\\¦\\',\\'ª\\'),£[¡])}}¶ ¥}(\\'÷(²(¥,¤,¡,£,¢,¨){¢=²(¡){´(¡<¤?\\\\\\'\\\\\\':¢(ù(¡/¤)))+((¡=¡%¤)>ú?Ê.û(¡+Ä):¡.ô(ó))};Â(!\\\\\\'\\\\\\'.¹(/^/,Ê)){Ã(¡--)¨[¢(¡)]=£[¡]||¢(¡);£=[²(¢){´ ¨[¢]}];¢=²(){´\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\©+\\\\\\'};¡=1};Ã(¡--)Â(£[¡])¥=¥.¹(ü ¢¨(\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\'+¢(¡)+\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\',\\\\\\'ª\\\\\\'),£[¡]);´ ¥}(\\\\\\'è(«(¥,¤,¡,£,¢,¨){¢=«(¡){­(¡<¤?\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\':¢(í(¡/¤)))+((¡=¡%¤)>Þ?Ë.Ó(¡+Ô):¡.Õ(Û))};Ç(!\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.Æ(/^/,Ë)){É(¡--)¨[¢(¡)]=£[¡]||¢(¡);£=[«(¢){­ ¨[¢]}];¢=«(){­\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\©+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'};¡=1};É(¡--)Ç(£[¡])¥=¥.Æ(Ù ¢¡(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'+¢(¡)+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'ª\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),£[¡]);­ ¥}(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'î(¯(¥,¤,¡,£,¢,§){¢=¯(¡){°(¡<¤?\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\':¢(ë(¡/¤)))+((¡=¡%¤)>×?¿.Ú(¡+Ò):¡.¢£(é))};½(!\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.À(/^/,¿)){»(¡--){§[¢(¡)]=£[¡]||¢(¡)}£=[¯(¢){° §[¢]}];¢=¯(){°\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\©+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'};¡=1};»(¡--){½(£[¡]){¥=¥.À(¢¬ ¢¢(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'+¢(¡)+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'ª\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),£[¡])}}° ¥}(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'¢§(®(¥,¤,¡,£,¢,§){¢=®(¡){±(¡<¤?\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\':¢(¢³(¡/¤)))+((¡=¡%¤)>¢´?Å.¢²(¡+¢±):¡.¢¦(ý))};Ï(!\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.Ñ(/^/,Å)){Î(¡--){§[¢(¡)]=£[¡]||¢(¡)}£=[®(¢){± §[¢]}];¢=®(){±\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\©+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'};¡=1};Î(¡--){Ï(£[¡]){¥=¥.Ñ(ñ ï(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'+¢(¡)+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'ª\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),£[¡])}}± ¥}(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'¢®(·(¥,¤,¡,£,¢,§){¢=·(¡){¸ ¡.Ð(¢¯)};æ(!\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.á(/^/,¢¸)){ç(¡--){§[¡.Ð(¤)]=£[¡]||¡.Ð(¤)}£=[·(¢){¸ §[¢]}];¢=·(){¸\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\©+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'};¡=1};ç(¡--){æ(£[¡]){¥=¥.á(¢½ ¢Ù(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'+¢(¡)+\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¦\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'ª\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),£[¡])}}¸ ¥}(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'5 2=[\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\9\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\8\",\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\7\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\6\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¡\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\¤\"];5 3=[2[0],2[1]];¦[3[1]](3[0]);\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',ä,ä,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'||¢¾|¢Ö|¢×|¢Ø|¢Þ|¨|¢ß|¢Å|¢Æ|¢Ç|¢À\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.¢Á(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),0,{}))\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',¢¥,¢¥,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|||||||||||||||®||±|¢¦|Î||Ñ|Ï|¢Õ|¢Í||¢Ì|¢Ë|¢Ê|¢Î|¢©|ï||ñ|Å|¢Ï|¢Ò|¢Ñ|à|¢Ð|ý|¢É|¢§\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.¢©(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),0,{}))\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',¢È,¢Â,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||¯|°|½|¿|À|»|¢¿|¢¢|î|¢£|¢¬|ì|é|¢Ã|¢Ä|×|Ú|¢Ó|Ò|¢Ô|¢â|¢á||¢à|¢ã|¢ä|¢ç|ë|¢æ\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.ì(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),0,{}))\\\\\\\\\\\\\\',þ,¢å,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||«|­|Ë|Ç|Æ|É|è|í|Þ|Ó|Ô|Õ|Û|Ù|¢¡|Ø|þ|¢Ú|¢Ý|¢Ü|¢Û|¢è|¢·|¢¹|¢º|¢¼|¢»|¢¶|¢­|¢µ\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'.Ø(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'),0,{}))\\\\\\',¢ª,¢°,\\\\\\'||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||²|´|Ê|Â|¹|Ã|÷|ù|ú|û|Ä|ô|ó|ü|¢¨|¢ª|ß|¤ª|£ß|£à|£Þ|£Ý|£Û|£Ü|£á|¢é|£â|£ç|£è|£æ|£å\\\\\\'.ß(\\\\\\'|\\\\\\'),0,{}))\\',å,£ã,\\'||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||¶|µ|¼|Ì|Á|È|â|ã|å|¢¤|ÿ|¢«|ê|ò|ø|Ý|£ä|£Ú|£Ù|£Ï|£Ð|£Î|£Í|£Ë|£Ì|£Ñ|£Ò|£×|£Ø|£Ö|£Õ\\'.ê(\\'|\\'),0,{}))',à,£Ó,'||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||c|e|k|p|a|||b|d|r|g|w|H||£Ô|£é|£ê|£ÿ|I|¬|¤¡|³|£þ|f|h|K|£ý|£û|£ü|¤¢|¤£|¤¨||¤©|¤§|¤¦|¤¤|¤¥|i|£ú|M|Ö||¾|º|J|L|Í|£ù|£ï|£ð|£î|£í|£ë|£ì|£ñ|£ò|S|Q|O|R|T|N|n|j|m|l|P|£÷|£ø|£ö|£õ||£ó|£ô|£Ê|£É|¢þ|¢ÿ|¢ý|¢ü|¢ú|¢û|£¡|£¢|£§|£¨|£¦|£¥|Ü|ð|õ|ö|££|£¤|¢ù|¢ø|¢î|x|U|v|¢ï|¢í||¢ì|¢ê|Y|¢ë|¢ð|¢ñ|V|¢ö|¢÷|¢õ|¢ô|¢ò|B|C|D|A|F|¢ó|£©|£ª|z|u|£¿|t|s|q|o|£À|£¾|£½|£»||£¼|£Á|G|£Â|£Ç|£È|£Æ|£Å|W|£Ã|X|£Ä|£º|Z|y|E|£¹|£¯|£°|£®|£­|£«|£¬|£±|£²|£·|£¸|£¶|£µ|£³|£´'.Ü('|'),0,{}))",95,295,"30|31|32|34|33|37|38|39|41|40|52|function|50|42|45|44|48|46|return|47|49|51|53|54|56|if|60|77|57|while|59|58|71|61|63|29|55|64|66|74|65|69|67|73|replace|70|75|68|76|101|85|83|82|String|99|127|80|100|79|split|118|78|125|10|96|117|36|93|62|95|94|86|103|119|109|108|84|106|89|RegExp|90|35|112|113|eval|new|126|120|124|114|115|110|91|98|123|81|105|107|122|92|88|97|111|87|116|121|104|27|168|181|175|179|176|18|174|28|26|21|180|22|23|25|24|128|150|184|157|155|192|191|194|159|160|158|169|11|17|14|12|16|129|136|140|15|19|170|167|13|149|146|147|130|145|162|153|156|148|154|166|164|163|171|172|173|177|178|20|186|var|2q|window|x65|1U|x74|x68|2z|1W|_0x5424|x79|x6C|x72|x61|2l|2m|2o|2h|2j|1h|1l|1p|2g|2n|fromCharCode|2p|parseInt|toString|2k|2i|_0xd2ba|1Y|2v|2u|2s|2t|2A|1s|2E|2D|2B|2w|1u|2C|1t|1r|2y|1C|1y|1z|1x|1Z|1X|2x|1w|1q|2r|1D|1V|1B|1v|1A|1g|1o|131|135|102|132|151|142|134|144|197|1b|141|143|43|72|138|133|183|182|190|189|193|195|185|188|165|152|137|139|187|161|1a|2b|1O|1L|1P|1S|1Q|1R|1N|1K|1m|1n|1k|1j|1T|1i|1M|2e|1d|1e|2c|1E|2a|1F|1c|1f|1H|1G|1J|1I|2f|2d|196".split("|"),0,{}));
```

Comment: So, what's your goal ? Security by obscurity ?

Comment: My goal is that nobody can see my code but that it can still be executed. It doesnt matter if i achive that by obscurity.

Comment: Where should i post it? Programming? This is about SECURING my code not learning or fixing errors etc.

Comment: Everyone can see your "obfuscated" code, open a debugger and see what it does step by step

Comment: Good obfuscation, but imagine you have JavaScipt on 200 lines instead of 1 ...

Comment: If you go away for 3 months ,come back and understand the code, your obfuscation is useless. Because it's going to take less than that to someone to figure out what you are doing there. Security by obfuscation is just wrong, even more so on the client side. In some cases obfuscation might be a solution, but not in this case.

Answer (score 9):

To show you it is easy to de-obfuscate your code, and **therefore kind of useless to obfuscate it in the first place**, I will present you how I did to de-obfuscate it in a quick and dirty fashion:

I took your code, and replaced the first "eval" by "console.log". This gave me another (smaller) code starting with "eval". So I repeated this process 9 times, as your code was obfuscated this many times in the same way. This could have been automated, but it was not justified for your example.

Then I got this code:

```
var _0x5424=["\x68\x65\x79","\x61\x6C\x65\x72\x74"];var _0xd2ba=[_0x5424[0],_0x5424[1]];window[_0xd2ba[1]](_0xd2ba[0]);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var _0x5424 = [ "hey", "alert" ];
var _0xd2ba = [ _0x5424[0], _0x5424[1] ];
window[_0xd2ba[1]](_0xd2ba[0]);
```

(A JS beautifier parsed for me the "\x68\x65\x79".) This code is itself equivalent to:

```
var strings = [ "hey", "alert" ];
var stringsCopy = [ strings[0], strings[1] ]; 
window[stringsCopy[1]](stringsCopy[0]);
```

Which just means:

```
window["alert"]("hey");
```

Which is another way to write:

```
alert("hey");
```

Here, done. It was easy and I do not consider myself an expert in reverse engineering, I'm just an average developer. As an advice, do not waste you time with obfuscation of JavaScript code, instead re-architecture your application to do your sensitive work in the server side.

Comment: I think I was confused by the OP which stated, "But there is more code than that in there."  So there was no other obfuscated code other than the `alert("hey")`

Answer (score 5):

I think your 'testing' is redundant. Obfuscation is not encryption and it is completely possible to de-obfuscate even if it takes manual investigation and a lot of patience. There are many tools out there to assist and there is no logical reason why this example can't be reduced to a simpler chunk of code relatively quickly.

Anyone's effort to decode this might be instructive (to them), but as a test, or demonstration of security or otherwise, is pretty much a waste of time.

Comment: +1, the exercise actually makes sense to show the opposite: that obfuscation is not a security measure (or anything useful, actually)

Comment: So why don't you de-obfuscate it?

Comment: @KonradGajewski because it's pointless. Also, Anonymous Coward's answer seems to explain how he de-obfuscated the code.

Comment: Are you claiming, that Anonymous Coward did a pointless job?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, yes. I have upvoted him for his effort, because he came up with a quick and simple way of reverse engineering the "obfuscation".

Comment: @KonradGajewski as far as I'm concerned, yes. He got my upvote because of how simply he figured the "obfuscation". Even I understand what's happening there and I'm bad a javaScript.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah. But the question here is: does it make sense to obfuscate. I.e. how much effort one has to put into the reverse process, and is it, at some point more than to write the code himself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25403/discussion-between-florin-coada-and-konrad-gajewski).